# Difference between returning a Generator and yield values

Tags: python

I encountered a problem with two pieces of code: one successfully executed, while the other did not, resulting in a ValueError related to an I/O operation on a closed file. Can you explain why one code snippet failed and the other succeeded, highlighting the differences between them?

## Invalid

```py
def get_file_rows(path: str):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        lines = (line.strip() for line in file)
    return lines

lines = get_file_rows("test.txt")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

*ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.*

## Valid

```py
def get_file_rows(path: str):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            yield line.strip()

lines = get_file_rows("test.txt")
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your first sample is equivalent to

```
def _generator(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.strip()

def get_file_rows(path: str):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        return _generator(file)
```

And generator functions like `_generator`, when called, do not start their execution yet, they only return a generator iterator. That code only gets executed when it is iterated over, by which time control flow has left the `with`-statement and the file has been closed.

By contrast, in your second example, the `with` statement is only entered at the start of iteration over `lines` and only exits after the iterator is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you've created a generator object that works on `file`, but at the conclusion of the `with` block, the file is closed, and thus cannot be read from. The generator is returned, but can't be used.

In the second, the file remains open for reading throughout the loop. Only at the end of the loop and thus the `with` block is the file closed.